# real time validation of username and email address using ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I set up a simple form and use ajax+jquery to check for valid username (doesn't exist in DB) and email address (valid format and doesn't exist in DB) as follows

```
<body>
<div>
<h5> Sign Up </h5>
<hr />
<div>
    Username:<input type="text" size="32" name="membername" id="username"><div id="usernameStatus"></div><br />
    Email:<input type="text" size="32" name="memberemail" id="memberemail"><div id="emailStatus"></div><br/>
    Password:<input type="password" size="32" name="memberpwd"><br />
    <button id="signup"  disabled="true">Sign Up</button>   
</div>  
<script>    
    function IsEmailValidAndNew()
    {
         var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-+\s]+")|([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)|("[\w-+\s]+")([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*))(@((?:[\w-+]+\.)*\w[\w-+]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][\d]\.|1[\d]{2}\.|

[\d]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
        var success=false;
        $("#memberemail").change(function()
        {
            var email=$("#memberemail").val();
            success=patter.test(email);
            if(success)
            {
                $("#usernameStatus").html('<img align="absmiddle" src="loading.gif"/> Checking email...');
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"regcheckemail.php",
                    data:"memberemail="+email,  
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#emailStatus").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            if(msg=="OK")
                            {
                                $("#memberemail").removeClass("object_error");
                                $("#memberemail").addClass("object_ok");
                                $(this).html('<img align="absmiddle" src="checkmark.png"/>');
                                success=true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $("#memberemail").removeClass('object_ok'); 
                                $("#memberemail").addClass("object_error");
                                $(this).html(msg);
                                success=false;
                            }
                        }
                        );
                    }
                }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                $("#emailStatus").html("Provided email address is ill-formed");
                $("#memberemail").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                $("#memberemail").addClass("object_error");
                success=false;
            }
        }
        );
        return success;
    }

    function IsUserAlreadyExist()
    {
        var success=false;
        $("#username").change(function()
        {
            var usr=$("#username").val();
            if(usr.length>=7)
            {
                $("#usernameStatus").html('<img align="absmiddle" src="loading.gif"/> Checking availability...');
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"regcheckuser.php",
                    data:"username="+usr,   
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#usernameStatus").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            if(msg=="OK")
                            {
                                $("#username").removeClass("object_error");
                                $("#username").addClass("object_ok");
                                $(this).html('<img align="absmiddle" src="checkmark.png"/>');
                                success=true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); 
                                $("#username").addClass("object_error");
                                $(this).html(msg);
                                success=false;
                            }
                        }
                        );
                    }
                }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                $("#usernameStatus").html("The username should have at least 7 characters");
                $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); 
                $("#username").addClass("object_error");
                success=false;
            }
        });
        return success;
    }
    $(document).ready(function()
    {       
        if(IsEmailValidAndNew() && IsUserAlreadyExist())
        {
            $('button').find("#signup").attr("disabled","false");
        }
        else
        {
            $('button').find("#signup").attr("disabled","true");    
        }           
    });
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

I use notepad to code it, it doesn't work and I can't find out the mistake. I don't know any good tool you might be using to code in javascript that has awesome options like an embedded intellisense and debug capability.

Comment: Concerning Javascript debugging I highly recommended you the FireBug plugin for FireFox web browsser. By adding a few 'console.log("message")' you can track the flow of your script in the console provided by the plugin! https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: Where's the <head>? Can we assume you have included the jQuery library files?

Comment: Further to what yoshi said, if you happen to already use the Chrome browser it has debugging tools built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

1. Your email regex is not thorough enough (OK, this isn't actually stopping the code working, but it's the first thing I noticed).
2. Your ajax calls are *asynchronous,* which is good, but means that the functions that do the `$.ajax()` calls will complete *before* the ajax response is received. You need to restructure this to do something from the ajax success callback.
3. You don't need the `ajaxComplete()` function - you're already within an ajax success handler at that point so put the code within your current `ajaxComplete()` directly in the containing success function.
4. You call `IsEmailValidAndNew()` and `IsUserAlreadyExist()` once from your document ready and disable or enable the "signup" control, but at no point after that do you re-enable or re-disable it. You are calling these functions as if they will validate the fields, but really what they do is set up change handlers on the fields so the code in the functions won't do anything until the fields actually get changed by the user.

Following is one way you could structure your code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var emailOK = false,
        nameOK = false;

    function setSubmitEnabling() {
       $("#signup").prop("disabled", !(emailOK && nameOK));
    }

    setSubmitEnabling();

    $("#username").change(function() {
       var usr = $(this).val();
       if (usr.length < 7) {
           $("#usernameStatus").html("The username should have at least 7 characters");
           $(this).removeClass('object_ok').addClass("object_error");
           nameOK = false;
           setSubmitEnabling();
       } else {
           // format seems OK, so do ajax call:
           $("#usernameStatus").html('<img align="absmiddle" src="loading.gif"/> Checking availability...');
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url:"regcheckuser.php",
               data:"username="+usr,
               success : function(msg) {
                  if(msg === "OK")
                  {
                      $("#username").removeClass("object_error")
                                    .addClass("object_ok");
                      $("#usernameStatus").html('<img align="absmiddle" src="checkmark.png"/>');

                      nameOK = true;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      $("#username").removeClass('object_ok')
                                    .addClass("object_error");
                      $("#usernameStatus").html(msg);

                      nameOK = false;
                  }
                  // now update button state
                  setSubmitEnabling();
               }
           });
       }
    });

    $("#memberemail").change(function() {
       // basically the same thing as for the username field as shown above,
       // except setting emailOK instead of nameOK, so I suggest you get the
       // username part working first then come back to do this the same way
    });

});
```

The idea of the above code is that there are several points where you need to enable or disable the "signup" button, and that depends on two unrelated conditions. So create a flag for each of those conditions, and function `setSubmitEnabling()` that checks the flags and enables or disables the buttons. Call that function immediately when the page loads to set the initial enable/disable state, and call it again any time something changes that needs the enable/disable state to be re-evaluated.

Also, create a change handler for each of your two fields. The change handlers will be similar to each other, basically doing some initial quick validation to see if the length and format is OK and if so an ajax call to test for uniqueness.